# Pandas: Get ohlc data for every row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`with a `datetime` index and a price column. I want ohlc data. (open, high, low, close)

I want to resample this dataframe at a given frequency *at every row*.

`frame.resample('60S', how = 'ohlc')` works but now the dataframe's indexs are spaced 60 seconds apart. I want to resample at every row from the previous 60s worth of rows. (12 if indexs are 5s apart). That way I can have ohlc values for every row in the original dataframe.

I dont think what I want to do is possible with `df.resample` but possibly with `.agg` or `.map`?

How do I get ohlc data for *every* row?

```
n = 10000

prices = np.linspace(100.0, 103.0, n) + np.random.normal(0.0, 0.3, n)
f = pd.DataFrame({'price': prices}, index = pd.date_range(end = datetime.utcnow(), freq = '5S', periods = n))

ohlcized = f.resample('60S', how = 'ohlc') # resampling doesnt work (834 != 10000)
len(ohlcized) # 834
len(f) # 10000

if len(ohlcized) == len(f):
    print "question answered"
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data?

Comment: Done. If you need me to clarify more, I can. The issue is that resampling removes rows. I want to keep all the data and just preform the 'ohlc' operation at every row over the past 60S of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For equally spaced timestamps:

```
bars = 12  
df = pd.concat([f.shift(bars - 1), pd.rolling_max(f, bars), pd.rolling_min(f, bars), f], 
               axis=1)
df.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']

>>> df.tail()
                                  Open        High         Low       Close
2016-03-03 19:20:49.336236  102.510446  103.603518  102.438872  102.810945
2016-03-03 19:20:54.336236  102.916919  103.603518  102.438872  103.072880
2016-03-03 19:20:59.336236  103.603518  103.603518  102.438872  103.290665
2016-03-03 19:21:04.336236  102.966331  103.290665  102.438872  103.095781
2016-03-03 19:21:09.336236  102.438872  103.409546  102.438872  103.409546
```

Comment: rolling_min and rolling_max should be switched

Comment: Fixed it above.  Thanks.